# Show that $\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle \ne \Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ that is the set of all such sequences does not generate $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ be the set of all infinite sequences $(a_0, a_1, \dots)$ where $a_i \in \Bbb Z$ for $i \in \Bbb N$. This set is a group when we consider addition component-wise. If $e_i=(0, \dots,1,0,\dots)$ is a sequence with $1$ on the $i$'th index show that $$\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle \ne \Bbb Z^\Bbb N$$ that is the set of all such sequences does not generate $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$.

The inclusion $\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle \subset \Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ will probably hold as adding component-wise these $e_i$'s will give me elements of $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ however I fail to see how can $\Bbb Z^\Bbb N$ contain an element which cannot be made from summing $e_i$'s? Is it $(0,0, \dots)$ that cannot be made from any $e_i$'s?

Comment: How about the constant sequence $(1, 1, \ldots )$: how is it generated by the $e_i$'s?

Comment: The addition in a group is only defined for _finitely many_ summands, whereas $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ has elements with infinitely many nonzero entries

Comment: What is the definition of $\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's the subgroup generated by $e_i$'s.

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused What do you mean exactly? The problem statement defined the addition as $$(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots) + (b_0, b_1, b_2, \dots) = (a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots)$$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, yet $G=\langle \{e_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\rangle$ is countable generated and hence countable. As others have pointed out, the inequality is due to the fact that $G$ only contains finite sums of the $e_i$’s.

Comment: @SleepWalker what exactly does, "the subgroup generated by $e_i$'s" mean? Go back to the definition of "(sub)group" and "generated". [this is a hint that should help answer the question...].

Answer (score 1):

If $e_i = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ with a one in the $i$-th entry, and we add finitely many such elements, we will only ever have finitely many nonzero entries in the result. In other words, it is impossible to write
$(1,1,\ldots,)$, the element with all ones, as a *finite* sum of the $e_i$'s.

A group is generated by a set of elements if anything in the group can be written as a finite sum of the given elements.

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition of $\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle$ ?

Quoting from the first line of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group#Finitely_generated_group):

> In abstract algebra, a generating set of a group is a subset of the
> group set such that every element of the group can be expressed as a
> combination (under the group operation) of **finitely** many elements
> of the subset and their inverses.

In other words, every element of $\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle$ is a sequence with finitely many non-zero entries.

For example, $(1,1,1,...)$ cannot be expressed as a addition of **finitely** many $e_i,$ and therefore $(1,1,1,...) \not\in\langle \{e_i \mid i \in \Bbb N\}\rangle$